# How to set variable after get it's value

Tags: c#, variables, set

I want to set IsStringBuilderWritten to false after i get it's value. But i can't figure it out.

IsStringBuilderWritten must be false to use StringBuilder but i don't know how to set it's value therefore i can use StringBuilder just once. How can i solve this problem?

```
class FileWhatcher : IDisposable
{
    public event System.EventHandler StringBuilderWritten;

    protected virtual void OnstringBuilderWritten()
    {
        StringBuilderWritten?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private bool _isStringBuilderWritten;

    public bool IsStringBuilderWritten
    {
        get { return _isStringBuilderWritten; }
        set { _isStringBuilderWritten = value; 
              if (IsStringBuilderWritten) { OnstringBuilderWritten(); } 
            }
    }
}
```

And i use it in:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private FileWhatcher fw = new FileWhatcher();
    private List<StringBuilder> watchedInformation;

public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        watchedInformation = new List<StringBuilder>();
        fw.Start("F:\\slayt");
        fw.StringBuilderWritten += new System.EventHandler(delegate (object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            HandleComeNewWatch();
        });
    }

    private void HandleComeNewWatch()
    {
        if (fw.IsStringBuilderWritten)
        {
            watchedInformation.Add(fw.stringbuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would work. I added a temp variable to put the value of _isStringBuilderWritten, then set its value to false. Then return the temp.

```
public bool IsStringBuilderWritten
        {
            get { 
                 bool temp = _isStringBuilderWritten;
                 _isStringBuilderWritten = false;
                 return temp; 
                }
            set { _isStringBuilderWritten = value; 
                  if (IsStringBuilderWritten) { OnstringBuilderWritten(); } 
                }
        }
```